# why does sudo su; su tomcat doesn't switch to tomcat user?

Tags: linux, sudo, command, su

In Redhat linux. from my user if I issue command
sudo su -> changes to root
su tomcat --> changes to tomcat user

Why does tailing the commands in single line doesn't work?
sudo su; su tomcat --> stil in root. Doesn't switch to tomcat

Answer (score 15):

The commands

```
sudo su; su tomcat
```

are two commands. The shell will run the first and when it completes it will run the second. Note that the shell does not pass the second command as an argument to the first command.

When you exit the first command it will run the second

```
sudo su ; su tomcat
[sudo] password for iain:
root@host:iain]$ exit
exit
Password: <---- this is the prompt from the second su command.
```

You can use sudo to transition to the tomcat user directly

```
sudo -u tomcat <some command>
```

or use `-s` to get a shell e.g.

```
whoami
iain
sudo -s -u tomcat 
whoami
tomcat
```

Answer (score 5):

When you divide your `sudo` and `su` commands with a `;` sign the `su` will be executed after the `sudo` has finished. I.e. in that case you execute the `su` as your normal user.

To achieve your desired result try to execute the whole in one command:

```
sudo su - tomcat
```

Comment: And you might want to make sure you inherit `tomcat`'s environment as well; try `sudo su - tomcat`.

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes, of course ;) - I changed my answer

Comment: You already had my +1, can't add another - sorry!